# How can I insert a picture/graphic on an answer or comment?

Tags: support, images

The question is on the title, I read on the help how to include links, but the images I want to include are on my pc, not online. Is there a way to upload a file?

Alternatively, is there any public, free, user friendly, site where I can upload my files and then link them here?

(I mean, I would like to NOT register to a site, receive a passwd, periodic mails, ads...)

Comment: You have a button with a frame in the answer box, if you press it you can upload the photo that you prefer.

Comment: Great!!! I never realized that ha ha ha... and... does this work also for comments? (here I don't see any frame)

Comment: I know that this is not a math question, and that in fact it is a silly question, but I searched the help before asking and find no answer...

Comment: meta.stackexchange: [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) and [Is it possible to add images to comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments)

Comment: @user126154: images cannot be inserted into comments, however a [link to an image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OLfvM.png) can be used as usual.

Comment: In the future, if you have a question about the site or site features, please ask it on [Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com).  (Which is where this is now.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment you can use the button in the answer box if you are posting an answer. Here you have more info regarding the hosting site:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

And here you can see the options that you have for posting a comment. I think you can't post an image there:

https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: When I want to post image in the comment, I simply upload it using the editor for answers. Then I do not post the answer, just copy the url of the image from the draft and use this link in the comment.